# Replacing consecutive if statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement

In my code I have a lot of instances like this:

```
if (!valid){
    validate();
}
if (valid){
    \\ execute some code
}
```

and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this? First off, it's annoying to have to write a bunch of these consecutive if statements, and secondly, part of my code in `validate()` requires that I load a webview with a login page, and then login. Once I've reached the logged in page, I retrieve a value using JavaScript which then changes the value of `valid` to true if it matches. There's no real convenient `until` function, and using `while(!valid)` doesn't quite give me what I want.

Here is my `validate()`

```
private void validate(){

    class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(String content) {
            // grants access based on authorization level
            loggedIn = true;

            if(content.contains("OK")){
                valid = true;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log In Successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                valid = false;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Access Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            updateMenuTitles();
        }
    }

    // open up the login page
    final WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.login_webview);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            //once page is finished loading, check id="role" pass that value to showHTML
            if(url.contains(getString(R.string.loginURL))) {
                wv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "window.HTMLOUT.showHTML(document.getElementById('course-eval-status')" +
                        ".innerHTML);})()");
                wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                closeWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                    String failingUrl) {
            Log.w("LoginActivity: ", description);
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl(getString(R.string.loginURL));
    if(!loggedIn) {
        wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        closeWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        closeWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `validate()` change the value of `valid`?

Comment: This part of your question "part of my code in validate() requires typing into a browser, and the java code doesn't wait around for me to type" tells me that you did not describe a lot of relevant context.

Comment: The else keyword would clarify your code in the specific example you posted. Other than that, you're going to have to provide more context to what you're actually trying to do. "... doesn't quite give me what I want" kind of begs the question: what is it you want?

Comment: @MarsAtomic this isn't really an else situation. It's more of a "if a value's not true, attempt to make it true, and then execute some code if it is true

Comment: @Henry I'm not quite sure what you mean, does my edit clarify it?

Comment: Can you show the `validate` method? I guess it returns before the WebView is even shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but could this be what you are looking for?

```
boolean valid = false;

private boolean validate() {
    System.out.println("Validating");
    return true;
}

public void test() {
    if (valid || (valid = validate())) {
        System.out.println("Try 1");
    }
    if (valid || (valid = validate())) {
        System.out.println("Try 2");
    }
}
```

This will only call `validate` once. However - a better mechanism would be something like:

```
private boolean valid() {
    return valid || (valid = validate());
}

public void test2() {
    if (valid()) {
        System.out.println("Try 1");
    }
    if (valid()) {
        System.out.println("Try 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `validate()` changes the value of `valid`, then I don't really see a way around this.  It seems to me that the issue isn't so much syntactical as it is business logic.  You mention that your code "doesn't wait around" -- couldn't you change it to make it wait?  If not, then perhaps you need some unit tests to better be able to validate your code.  Regardless, the issue doesn't seem like it's with the `valid` flag.